# How run a control-broken IG as collapsed in the first place?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using Oracle APEX 21.2.5. I have an Interactive Grid. I did a control break on a specific column. I need to display all grid rows as collapsed when I first run the page. But it's displayed as expanded. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: did you try saving public report after you add control break and then collapsing it?

Comment: I did not and I can not collapse them one by one. There are many records.

Comment: Please, see if my solution exposed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73775526/interactive-grid-how-to-collaps-all-records/73837837#73837837 could help. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Please put the below code in the Javascript -> **Execute When Page Loads** section of the page

```
$("#YOUR_IG_STATIC_ID .a-GV-table tr.a-GV-controlBreak .a-GV-controlBreakHeader .a-Button.js-toggleBreak").click();
```

**Note:** In the above code replace YOUR_IG_STATIC_ID with the Static ID of your Interactive Grid region.