# Interactive Grid how to collaps all records

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, interactive-grid

I have a IG with control break to collapse grouped records based on varchar column.

The solution proposed in [How run a control-broken IG as collapsed in the first place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71736354/how-run-a-control-broken-ig-as-collapsed-in-the-first-place) by @akil_Ramesh is working fine for me but only when the report has few records. If the query returns more records the user needs to scroll down the page to see other records and in this case the control break will not be collapsed.

So the question is: there is a way to fetch all records in IG? Or another way to collpase control break after scroling down?

My setup: Apex 21.2, Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.3.0.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded a solution working for me:

- set IG pagination attribute = **page**
- create a DA for event "**Page change [Intercativ Grid]**" on your IG
- in True side: "Esecute Javascript code": **$("#*YOUR_STATIC-ID_IG* .a-GV-table tr.a-GV-controlBreak .a-GV-controlBreakHeader .a-Button.js-toggleBreak").click();**
  *(the code from @akil_Ramesh)*

Regards